# Where in the C++20 standard (N4860) does it say that an inline function must be defined before its use in a translation unit?

Tags: c++, c++20, inline, constexpr-function

[[dcl.constexpr]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1):

> The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or function template. The `consteval` specifier shall be applied only to the declaration of a function or function template. A function or static data member declared with the `constexpr` or `consteval` specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable ([dcl.inline]). If any declaration of a function or function template has a `constexpr` or `consteval` specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the same specifier.
>
> [Example 1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#example-1)
>
> ```
> constexpr void square(int &x);  // OK, declaration
> constexpr int bufsz = 1024;     // OK, definition
> constexpr struct pixel {        // error: pixel is a type
>   int x;
>   int y;
>   constexpr pixel(int);         // OK, declaration
> };
> constexpr pixel::pixel(int a)
>   : x(a), y(x)                  // OK, definition
>   { square(x); }
> constexpr pixel small(2);       // error: square not defined, so small(2) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>                                 // not constant ([expr.const]) so constexpr not satisfied
>
> constexpr void square(int &x) { // OK, definition
>   x *= x;
> }
> constexpr pixel large(4);       // OK, square defined
> int next(constexpr int x) {     // error: not for parameters
>      return x + 1;
> }
> extern constexpr int memsz;     // error: not a definition
> ```

I presume that the error highlighted above with the characters `<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<` is related with the [third sentence](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-3) in [dcl.constexpr]/1, that is:

> A function or static data member declared with the constexpr or consteval specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable ([dcl.inline]).

But I couldn't find anything in C++20 (N4860) that would establish the assertion that an inline function  has to be defined before its use in a translation unit.

Comment: when you do `constexpr pixel small(2);` you need to create `small` right then and there, but you can't at that point as `square` is not yet defined.  the compiler only works in a single pass in this case

Comment: @NathanOliver But where in the C++ 20 standard does it say that `the compiler only works in a single pass in this case`

Comment: Tag as **language-lawyer** to get a proper answer on this issue. AFAIK, the error in your snippet is that any function called inside `constexpr` context must have a visible definition. Since you declared `small` as `constexpr`, its constructor is forced to run in `constexpr` context - which demands that the definition of  `square` be visible. This was one of the rules back when `constexpr` was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @JohnKalane Sorry, I didn't realize you were quoting the example from the standard. I am not a fan of it, but the examples in the standard are sometimes written like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constexpr pixel small(2);` is ill-formed, because the initialization of a variable declared `constexpr` shall be a constant expression and an expression is disqualified from being a constant expression per [[expr.const]/5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const#5.3) if a call to an undefined constexpr function is made in it. In your case the call to `square` in `small`'s constructor call is the cause.

It isn't specified well when exactly the function needs to be defined (see [CWG issue 2166](https://wg21.link/cwg2166)), but in either reasonable interpretation, `square` in your example is not defined before the relevant point, which is either the lexical point of the call itself or the lexical point of the (head of the) constant expression itself (i.e. at `small`'s definition).

---

This is specific to the consequences of `constexpr` and has nothing to do with `inline`. An inline function generally does *not* have to be defined before its use in a translation unit. It just has to be defined *somewhere* in the translation unit.

Comment: I'm inclined to accept your answer, but the issue 2166 was posted in August 2015 and so far nothing has been decided about this!! One other point was that I couldn't quite understand what the OP wrote in there: "the function must be defined prior to the outermost evaluation that eventually results in the invocation". Could you clarify?

Comment: @JohnKalane "_the function must be defined prior to the outermost evaluation that eventually results in the invocation_" refers to the point containing the constant expression itself (rather than the nested call), i.e. in your example the definition of `small`.

Comment: @JohnKalane The issue is not particularly important. As mentioned in it, there is a known intention, so even without a resolution one can reasonably assume a specific behavior. A decision would only be relevant to special cases anyway, e.g. if the definition of `square` was between the definition of `pixel::pixel` and of `small`. Normally `constexpr` functions are defined in their first declaration, so this is an unusual situation in practice. The issues can stay open for many years if there is no push to resolve, some have been open for decades and have more practical relevance.

Comment: Many thanks for the excellent answer.